# Do official transistor counts include cache?

Tags: transistors, cache

Title says it all: do official transistor counts, such as [here](https://www.anandtech.com/show/7003/the-haswell-review-intel-core-i74770k-i54560k-tested/5), include the transistors needed to implement L1, L2, and L3 cache? I assume they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they typically include all transistors in the entire die, although sometimes counts are also given for individual components of the die as well.